# Evaluate $\int_{M}(F\cdot N)\,dS$

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, surface-integrals, multiple-integral

> Evaluate $\int_{M}(F\cdot N)\,dS$ where $F=(e^{\cos z},x^2,z)$ and $M=\{(x,y,z):z=1-(x^2+y^2),x^2+y^2\leq 1\}$

I try to use Stokes' theorem:

We will evaluate it on the curve $(\cos\theta,\sin\theta,0)$.

Therefore $$\int_0^{2\pi}(e,\cos^2\theta,0)\cdot (-\sin\theta,\cos\theta,0)d\theta =\int_0^{2\pi}-e\sin\theta+\cos^3\theta d\theta=0$$

Is it correct?

Comment: This is incorrect. To apply Stokes’s Theorem, you need to be finding the flux of the curl of $F$.

Comment: @TedShifrin but I am requested to find $\int F\cdot N dS$ so I must evaluate it straightforward ?

Comment: You can use the divergence theorem to make the surface over which you're integrating the unit disc in the $xy$ plane. I'm writing you a solution to redeem myself lol

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was waiting for Matthew's solution, but since he hasn't posted, here's a quick answer for you.

You can parametrize the surface and compute the surface integral directly. Polar coordinates is the easiest way to go. Let $\vec x(r,\theta) = (r\cos\theta,r\sin\theta,1-r^2)$, $0\le r\le 1$, $0\le\theta\le 2\pi$. Then
\begin{align*}
\int_S F\cdot N\,dS &= \int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^1 (e^{1-r^2},r^2\cos^2\theta,1-r^2)\cdot\left(\frac{\partial\vec x}{\partial r}\times\frac{\partial\vec x}{\partial\theta}\right)dr\,d\theta\\&=\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^1 (e^{1-r^2},r^2\cos^2\theta,1-r^2)\cdot r(2r\cos\theta,2r\sin\theta,1)\,dr\,d\theta \\
&= \int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^1  r\big(e^{1-r^2}2r\cos\theta+ 2r^3\cos^2\theta\sin\theta+1-r^2\big)dr\,d\theta \\
&=\pi/2.
\end{align*}
(Note it's easier to actually do the $\theta$ integral first, as the first two terms integrate to $0$ by symmetry.) I've assumed that the surface $S$ is oriented with $N$ pointing upward, but you didn't state so explicitly in your question.

Much easier is to apply the Divergence Theorem by closing up the surface with the disk $D$ on the bottom. Now, since $N$ points upward on the paraboloid, it must point downward on $D$. I will emphasize this by writing $D^-$ to denote the downward orientation. Then
$$\int_S F\cdot N\,dS + \int_{D^-} F\cdot N\,dS = \int_V \text{div}\,F\,dV = \int_V 1\,dV.$$
This means that
$$\int_S F\cdot N\,dS = \int_V 1\,dV + \int_{D^+} F\cdot N\,dS.$$
This makes sense. What enters the bottom disk plus the net sources inside $V$ tell you what leaves the paraboloid. In this case, $F\cdot N = z = 0$ on $D$, so we just get
$$\int_S F\cdot N\,dS = \int_V 1\,dV = \int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^1\int_0^{1-r^2}r\,dz\,dr\,d\theta = \frac{\pi}2;$$
indeed, this is precisely the same integral we had in the direct computation.

Comment: If we take the normal we get $(-2r^2cos\theta,-2r^2sin\theta,-r)$ why did you get all elements of the normal as positive?

Comment: First of all, I disagree with your computation. But, most important, as I said, you have to start off with an orientation on $S$ (which I said we were taking to be with upward-pointing normal) and then be sure that your parametrization is compatible with that.

Answer (score 2):

Define $\mathbb{D}:=\{(x,y,z)\in\mathbb{R}^3|z=0,x^2+y^2\leq1\}$ and take $E$ as the solid $$E=\{(x,y,z)\in\mathbb{R}^3|0\leq z\leq1-x^2-y^2\}$$ From the divergence theorem we can say $$\int_{E}(\nabla\cdot F)dV=\int_M(F\cdot N)dS+\int_{\mathbb{D}}(F\cdot N)dS$$ However, since $$\nabla \cdot F=\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\bigg[e^{\cos(z)}\bigg]+\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\bigg[{x^2}\bigg]+\frac{\partial}{\partial z}\bigg[{z}\bigg]=1$$ and $$\int_E (\nabla \cdot F)dV=\int_{-1}^{1}\int_{-\sqrt{1-x^2}}^{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\int_{0}^{1-x^2-y^2}dV=\frac{\pi}{2}$$ we can say that $$\int_{M}(F\cdot N)dS=\frac{\pi}{2}-\int_{\mathbb{D}}(F\cdot N)dS$$ In order to calculate $\int_{\mathbb{D}}(F\cdot N)dS$ we can parameterize $\mathbb{D}$ on $[0,1]\times[0,2\pi)$ by $$\vec{r}(u,v):=(u\sin(v),u\cos(v),0)$$  Notice our parameterization of $\mathbb{D}$ induces an outward pointing normal vector of $E$ which is required in order to apply the divergence theorem. Moreover, $$\int_{\mathbb{D}}(F\cdot N)dS=\int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_{0}^{1}\big[(F\circ\vec{r})(u,v)\cdot (\vec{r}_u\times\vec{r}_v)(u,v)\big]dudv=\int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_{0}^{1}\big[(e,u^2\sin^2(v),0)\cdot (0,0,-u)\big]dudv=0$$ Finally $$\int_{M}(F\cdot N)dS=\frac{\pi}{2}$$

Comment: Guess we overlapped after all. Two suggestions: Do the triple integral in cylindrical coordinates; and do the surface integral over the disk without bothering to parametrize. Subtracting the flux over the downward-oriented disk is just adding the flux over the upward-oriented disk, and then the normal is $\vec k$ and we have the usual area integral. But, yeah, we agree!!

Comment: Thank you. Your Latex skills must be insane to type a solution that quickly!

Comment: LOL, well, yeah. Close to 30 years of practice, including typesetting my four math textbooks :)